# Can I Change Track Attributes Without iTunes?

Tags: itunes, voice-memo

I accidentally changed the Media Kind of an Audiobook to Voice Memo. I've never used Voice Memos on my iPhone and can't see any way to browse voice memos in iTunes to correct the issue.

I have found the Audiobook files in the iTunes Media folder but when I drag them back into iTunes it's still categorised as Voice Memos. I even tried manually moving it into the Audiobook folder in iTunes Media but it doesn't show up under Audiobooks in iTunes.

Is there a way to change the Media Type of a file before importing it into iTunes? Or, is there a way to view this file in iTunes somehow so I can change the attributes in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a way but it's not easy!

1. Locate the file in the Media Type > Voice Memos folder.
2. Double-click one of the audiobook tracks to play it in iTunes.
3. Right-click the play-bar at the top of iTunes and choose Get Info and you can change that track back to an Audiobook.

[image]

4. You could do this for every track but in my case I found that doing this revealed all of the Audiobook tracks under My Music even though they were still tagged as Voice Memos. So I could select all tracks from there and use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to convert them all to Audiobooks in one hit.

Quite a long workaround but hopefully this will help someone else, I'm just glad my audiobooks are playable again :)